# Finding the text of a label using Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

Finding the text of a label using Capybara

Background: I have a KBA page and a set of question and answers, the answers are in the form of 5 possible answers using radio buttons. So I need to cycle through each label for each radio button to match up with valid answers in a yaml file.

HTML:

```
<div class="questions"></div>
<div class="answers"></div>
  <p>
    <label>
     <input id="answers_question_0_1" type="radio" checked="checked" value="1" name="answers[question_0]"></input>
     RADIO BUTTON TEXT 1
    </label>
  </p>
  <p></p> #another radio button and label text 2
  <p></p> #another radio button and label text 3
  <p></p> #another radio button and label text 4
  <p></p> #another radio button and label text 5
```

My test code:

```
  def answer_questions

   .
   .
   . 

   i=0

   def answers
     page.all('.answers')
   end

   #This is accessing the answer value from the selected correct question from the kba.yml file
   valid_answers = this variable contains the valid answer to the question

   #********THIS IS THE PROBLEM BLOCK*****************************
   #Set the radio buttons if they match one of the answers
   @correct_answer = answers[i].all(:radio_button).find do |radio|
     valid_answers.include?(radio.parent.text)
   end
   #********THIS IS THE PROBLEM BLOCK*****************************      

   i +=1

   unless @correct_answer
     p "Unable to answer question: #{question_text}" and next
   end

   @correct_answer.select

  end
```

The problem lies in the "problem block" noted in the above code snippet. I can't figure out how to get the text that is tied to one label/p tag per radio button, instead ALL radio button's text are returned and checked against the variable "valid_answers" and that always fails.

I basically want `radio.button.text` to equal "RADIO BUTTON TEXT 1" for it's respective radio button. But instead `radio.button.text` returns:

RADIO BUTTON TEXT 1 RADION BUTTON TEXT 2 RADIO BUTTON TEXT 3 etc.

I'm guessing it shouldn't be `radio.parent.text` but something else, which I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're making this more complicated than it needs to be - you should just be able to do

```
answers[i].choose("the text of the radio button you want to select")
```

You can catch an exception if the value isn't found and output your warning there.

Note: parent in a Capybara element is not the HTML parent of that element - it's the element that a finder was called on when locating the given element - so in your case it's the .answers element.  If you do want access to the nodes actual HTML parent element you can call `element.find(:xpath, '..')`

Comment: Tom, thanks, you led me down the right path, just changed what you said slightly:       

answers[i].choose(valid_answer[0])